# Sign-up policy - Set user attributes through code

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

I want to programatically set user attributes for the sign up policy. I saw a previous question ([Pass parameters to Sign-up policy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35758844/pass-parameters-to-sign-up-policy))  asked over a year ago and it was not possible at the time. Any update on this?

Is this possible with the [AuthenticationProperties.Dictionary](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/security/microsoft.owin.security.authenticationproperties.dictionary?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=fsharp) property? Something like this?

```cs
HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Set("Policy", Startup.SignUpPolicyId);

var authenticationProperties = new AuthenticationProperties();
authenticationProperties.Dictionary.Add("myattribute", "myvalue");

HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.Challenge(authenticationProperties);
```

Answer (score 5):

This can be implemented using a custom policy.

A working sample of passing an input claim from a relying party application to a custom policy (e.g. an invitation flow as a sign-up policy) is [here](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-advanced-policies/tree/master/wingtipgamesb2c).

In the `WingTipGamesWebApplication` project, the `InvitationController` controller class has two action methods, `Create` and `Redeem`.

The `Create` action method sends a signed redemption link to the email address for the invited user. This redemption link contains this email address.

The `Redeem` action method handles the redemption link. It passes the email address, as the **verified_email** claim in a JWT that is signed with the client secret of the Wingtip Games application (see the `CreateSelfIssuedToken` method in the `Startup` class in the `WingTipGamesWebApplication` project), from the redemption link to the **Invitation** policy.

The **Invitation** policy can be found at [here](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-advanced-policies/blob/master/wingtipgamesb2c/Policies/b2ctechready.onmicrosoft.com_B2C_1A_invitation.xml).

The **Invitation** policy declares the **verified_email** claim as an input claim:

```xml
<RelyingParty>
  <DefaultUserJourney ReferenceId="Invitation" />
  <TechnicalProfile Id="Invitation">
    <InputTokenFormat>JWT</InputTokenFormat>
      <CryptographicKeys>
        <Key Id="client_secret" StorageReferenceId="WingTipGamesClientSecret" />
    </CryptographicKeys>
    <InputClaims>
      <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_VerifiedEmail" />
    </InputClaims>
  </TechnicalProfile>
</RelyingParty>
```

The **extension_verifiedEmail** claim type, which is declared as a read-only field (so that it can't be modified by the end user), is mapped to the **verified_email** input claim:

```xml
<BuildingBlocks>
  <ClaimsSchema>
    <ClaimType Id="extension_VerifiedEmail">
      <DisplayName>Verified Email</DisplayName>
      <DataType>string</DataType>
      <DefaultPartnerClaimTypes>
        <Protocol Name="OAuth2" PartnerClaimType="verified_email" />
        <Protocol Name="OpenIdConnect" PartnerClaimType="verified_email" />
        <Protocol Name="SAML2" PartnerClaimType="http://schemas.wingtipb2c.net/identity/claims/verifiedemail" />
      </DefaultPartnerClaimTypes>
      <UserInputType>Readonly</UserInputType>
    </ClaimType>
  </ClaimsSchema>
</BuildingBlocks>
```

The **Invitation** user journey can be found in [here](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-advanced-policies/blob/master/wingtipgamesb2c/Policies/b2ctechready.onmicrosoft.com_B2C_1A_base.xml).

The second orchestration step of the **Invitation** user journey executes the **LocalAccount-Registration-VerifiedEmail** technical profile:

```xml
<UserJourney Id="Invitation">
  <OrchestrationSteps>
    ...
    <OrchestrationStep Order="2" Type="ClaimsExchange">
      <ClaimsExchanges>
        ...
        <ClaimsExchange Id="LocalAccountRegistrationExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="LocalAccount-Registration-VerifiedEmail" />
      </ClaimsExchanges>
    </OrchestrationStep>
  </OrchestrationSteps>
</UserJourney>
```

The **LocalAccount-Registration-VerifiedEmail** technical profile copies from the **extension_verifiedEmail** claim to the **email** claim and then displays the sign-up form with the verified email address (the **extension_verifiedEmail** claim):

```xml
<TechnicalProfile Id="LocalAccount-Registration-VerifiedEmail">
  <DisplayName>WingTip Account</DisplayName>
  <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.SelfAssertedAttributeProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
  <Metadata>
    <Item Key="ContentDefinitionReferenceId">api.localaccount.registration</Item>
    <Item Key="IpAddressClaimReferenceId">IpAddress</Item>
    <Item Key="language.button_continue">Create</Item>
  </Metadata>
  <CryptographicKeys>
    <Key Id="issuer_secret" StorageReferenceId="TokenSigningKeyContainer" />
  </CryptographicKeys>
  <InputClaimsTransformations>
    <InputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateEmailFromVerifiedEmail" />
  </InputClaimsTransformations>
  <InputClaims>
    <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_VerifiedEmail" />
  </InputClaims>
  <OutputClaims>
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_VerifiedEmail" Required="true" />
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="newPassword" Required="true" />
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="reenterPassword" Required="true" />
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="displayName" Required="true" />
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="authenticationSource" DefaultValue="localAccountAuthentication" />
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="executed-SelfAsserted-Input" DefaultValue="true" />
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="newUser" />
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" />
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="sub" />
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="userPrincipalName" />
  </OutputClaims>
  <ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
    <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="AzureActiveDirectoryStore-WriteUserByEmail-ThrowIfExists" />
  </ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
  <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SSOSession-AzureActiveDirectory" />
</TechnicalProfile>
```

This **LocalAccount-Registration-VerifiedEmail** technical profile references the **AzureActiveDirectoryStore-WriteUserByEmail-ThrowIfExists** validation technical profile that saves the local account with the verified email address (the **email** claim):

```xml
<TechnicalProfile Id="AzureActiveDirectoryStore-WriteUserByEmail-ThrowIfExists">
  <Metadata>
    <Item Key="Operation">Write</Item>
    <Item Key="RaiseErrorIfClaimsPrincipalAlreadyExists">true</Item>
  </Metadata>
  <IncludeInSso>false</IncludeInSso>
  <InputClaims>
    <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" PartnerClaimType="signInNames.emailAddress" Required="true" />
  </InputClaims>
  <PersistedClaims>
    <PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="displayName" />
    <PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" PartnerClaimType="signInNames.emailAddress" />
    <PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="givenName" />
    <PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="newPassword" PartnerClaimType="password" />
    <PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="passwordPolicies" DefaultValue="DisablePasswordExpiration" />
    <PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="surname" />
    <PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="verified.strongAuthenticationPhoneNumber" PartnerClaimType="strongAuthenticationPhoneNumber" />
  </PersistedClaims>
  <OutputClaims>
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="newUser" PartnerClaimType="newClaimsPrincipalCreated" />
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" />
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="signInNames.emailAddress" />
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="userPrincipalName" />
  </OutputClaims>
  <OutputClaimsTransformations>
    <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateSubject" />
  </OutputClaimsTransformations>
  <IncludeTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="AzureActiveDirectoryStore-Common" />
  <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SSOSession-AzureActiveDirectory" />
</TechnicalProfile>
```

Comment: Uservoice feedback: [make it easier to pass in claims](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/suggestions/32070931-make-it-easier-to-pass-claims-into-a-policy)

Comment: The feature suggestion must have been getting a lot of votes as they appear to have deleted it.

Comment: Feedback link update: [make it easier to pass in claims](https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/idea/9750399e-bf25-ec11-b6e6-000d3a4f0789)