# Pass value for pre-populate a custom field in Azure AD B2C

Tags: asp.net, azure, azure-ad-b2c

I want to send a value (of Client Number) from my backend to the sign-up page of Azure AD B2C. I need to create a claim : Client Number but how to pass this information to Azure AD B2C to have a textbox in readonly with the client number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be implemented using a custom policy.

A working sample of passing an input claim from a relying party application to a custom policy (e.g. an invitation flow as a sign-up policy) is [here](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-advanced-policies/tree/master/wingtipgamesb2c).

A full explanation of this invitation flow is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46984166/sign-up-policy-set-user-attributes-through-code/46996797#46996797).

Comment: is this valid approach in 2022? this seems complex and I'm not sure if they have come up with something different